# IE table cell border bug with colspan set

Tags: html, css

I have the following sample table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>t1</th>
            <th>t2</th>
            <th>t3</th>
            <th>t4</th>
            <th>t5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Colspan=5 here</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the simple CSS code:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

The weird thing is the bottom border after first `th` disappeared, here is a screenshot:

[image: IE cell border bug]

When I switch to another window and switch back to IE, the table *refresh* as normal. For the convenient, I create a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hulufei/3dxt2/9/

This effect IE10, 9, 8. Is there a fix for this bug in IE?

Comment: I don't have the bug in my IE 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: For what it's worth, I've just tested your fiddle using IE11, IE9 and IE8, and I'm not seeing the bug.

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue in any IE version.

Comment: You're missing the `tr` around `<td colspan="5">Colspan=5 here</td>`

Comment: It seems the jsFiddle only reproduce in IE10, a simple local page can reproduce this bug in IE10, 9, 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the style code as this seems solve the problem:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
th, td {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>t1</th>
        <th>t2</th>
        <th>t3</th>
        <th>t4</th>
        <th>t5</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">Colspan=5 here</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```